# Why is my startAlarm and updateTimeText not working?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a time picker dialog using fragments and I want it so that the time chosen from the dialog is shown after choosing. However, after placing logcats, I found out that the startAlarm and updateTimeText functions weren't even running to begin with. Any ideas why?
Here is my code for the onTimeSet that calls these 2 functions:

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
        Log.e("time", "test1");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        updateTimeText(c);
        startAlarm(c);
        Log.e("Time", "settime");
    }
```

And here are the 2 functions in question:

```
private void updateTimeText(Calendar c){

        String timeText = "Alarm set for: ";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());

    //    String timeText = "testing";
        mTextView.setText(timeText);
        Log.e("time", "time");
    }

    private void startAlarm(Calendar c){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        mTextView.setText("Testing");
        Log.e("Start", "start");
    }
```

Here is the TimePickerFragment dialog

```
public class TimePickerFragmentPage extends DialogFragment {

    TimePickerFragmentPage()
    {
    }

    TimePickerFragmentPage(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener){
        this.onTimeSetListener = onTimeSetListener;
    }
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                Log.e("Time", "Test2");
            }

        }, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

And here is the piece of code that references the dialog

```
if (id == R.id.action_set_time){
            // move to time dialog
            TimePicker dialog = new TimePicker();
            // using bundle to pass room name and light inside dialog fragment
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("RoomID",light.getRoom());
            bundle.putString("LightID",light.getId());
            dialog.setArguments(bundle);
            dialog.show(getParentFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did the `onTimeSet` function run though? I can see you added a log line to it to

Comment: Nope, neither thing ran, the only thing that ran was the button press

Comment: So obviously the problem lies here - if `onTimeSet` would run the other two would too, you should first understand why the `onTimeSet` function won't get called. if you'd share more relevant code I might be able to help

Comment: Hi! I just added the dialog code and the piece of code that references it

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your `TimePickerFragmentPage`, you never call the `onTimeSetListener` that you predefined when creating the dialog object.
I guess its redunant and you don't need it, or you want to use it instead of `new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` (so instead of `return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){`, I think you mean `return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), onTimeSetListener());`, and then when you create a `TimePickerFragmentPage` object you'd need to provide a listener.

Second, isn't the `TimePickerFragmentPage` object your dialog?
If it is, when you reference the dialog, you should call `TimePickerFragmentPage dialog = new TimePickerFragmentDialog();`, and not `TimePicker dialog = new TimePicker()`, because then you never even use the custom dialog you've created.